# Combining of date field and time field to be 1 dateTime field

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am working on Angular/ Ionic. Currently, I have a date field and a time field.

I would like to combine both of these together and assign as a single variable.

Typescript.ts

```
var date = data[i].date;
var startTime = data[i].time;

console.log('this is the date: ' + date);
console.log('this is the StartTime: ' + startTime);

var startDateTime = moment(date).format('L') + new Date(startTime).toISOString();
```

This is the output
[image]

second method done was
typescript.ts

```
var date = data[i].date;
    var startTime = data[i].time;

    console.log('this is the date: ' + date);
    console.log('this is the StartTime: ' + startTime);

    var start = moment(date).format('L') + moment(startTime).format('LT');
    console.log(start);
```

[image]

Thankyou for all helps in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe. This will work for sure.

```
var startDate = moment(date).format('L');
var time = moment(startTime).format('LT');
var startDateTime = startDate + " " + time;
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace this line in your second method,

```
var start = moment(date).format('L') + moment(startTime).format('LT');
```

with this one,

```
var start = moment(date).format('L') +' '+startTime;
```

Comment: Ok, thankyou I guess this is the it? "03/04/2018 03:00 PM" However is this in string type or a date type now?

Comment: ahhh I tried to add 15 minutes to the date itself, but cannot. I tried with converting into date object           var startTime = moment(date).format('L') +' '+time;
          console.log(startTime);

          var endTime = moment(startTime).add(15,'minutes').calendar();
          console.log(endTime);
            startTime: new Date(startTime),
            endTime: new Date(endTime),